# Appending values to an iterable object while web crawling in python/BeautifulSoup (also want to know about multi-threading)

Tags: python, multithreading, web-crawler

I am coming here with a bug on my very first real python program (i.e. not something out of codeacademy).  I am an avid user of R and I built out a bunch of web crawling/scraping tools using the `XML` packages.  Unfortunately, I reached the point where R is just not ideal for some of the things that I am trying to do, so I am building some of these tools in Python and Hopefully you can help.  If there are any glaring python-specific coding best-practices that I'm neglecting, I would appreciate a heads-up as well.

I need to be able to append values to my iterable.  At each step of the iteration in the code below, the entire object `links_child` gets added to my the `links` object.  I actually need each link within `links_child` to be added separately to the object, rather than all as one entry.  This will keep growing and growing `links` and the iteration will only break when I reach a specified number of websites (100 in the code below).  Do any of you know how I can extract the bs4 items line-by-line and add them to my iterable object?  The error I get is as follows:

```
AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Also,  I ultimately want this crawler to be a heck of a lot faster.  What types of mutli-threading options (if any) do I have with beautifulsoup?  Should I switch libraries?  Are there any low-hanging fruits I can pick here that would boost my speed?  It would be perfect if there was a simple way to have 5-10 threads doing this crawl at once and updating the same dictionary object, but that is probably just a fantasy.

```
from urllib import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

base_site = "http://www.tasq.com"
page = urlopen(base_site).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
links = soup.find_all('a')
start_slash = re.compile('/')
link_db = {}
# iterate through all links on the homepage
for link in links:
    # print for debugging purposes
    print link
    # pull out the hrefs from the current link
    fullLink = str(link.get('href'))
    # print for debugging purposes
    print fullLink
    # see if the link is valid using regex
    check_start = start_slash.match(fullLink)
    # if the link is not valid, concatenate the domain
    if check_start <> None:
        fullLink = base_site + fullLink
    # fi the link is already stored as a key in the dict, skip it
    if fullLink in link_db:
        next
    # connect to the full link (O operation)
    page_child = urlopen(fullLink).read()
    # create bs4 object out of the opened page
    soup_child = BeautifulSoup(page_child)
    # insert the link as the key and some text string as the value
    link_db[fullLink] = 'example'
    # find all links on current page and save them in object
    links_child = soup_child.find_all('a')
    # (THIS IS THE SOURCE OF THE ERROR)append object with links to the iterable
    links.append(links_child)
    # break code if link_db gets to specified length
    if len(link_db) == 100:
        break
```

Comment: You shouldn't perform quality checks with `None`. Use `is` instead. `if check_start is not None:` Also, when do inequality checks, you'll probably want to use `!=` rather than `<>` as the latter has been removed from Python 3.

Comment: Your question is too broad; keep it to one issue per post please. I'd move the multithreading issue to a separate post.

Comment: Sorry about that, Martijn.  I'll keep that in mind for next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're cycling over `links` and you're appending over it as well. Eventually it hits the first `links_child` you added, which is a list of links not a `Tag` object and therefore doesn't have a `get` attribute.

Append the `links_child` to another variable and it works fine. You can also use `extend` instead of `append` to add the contents of `links_child` to `links` but it hits another problem further on trying to read a relative URL `../contact/contact-form.php` which you're not accounting for.

There's several ways to do multiprocessing in Python, the most popular is [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing#multiprocessing) as it gives you a nice API to work with along with spawning processes rather than threads which would fully make use of the multiple cores in the CPU.

There's a number of ways you can approach multiprocessing in this example. You could, for instance, define your main loop as a function add create a Pool of workers to work through it. Something like this:

```
from urllib import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import multiprocessing

def work(link):
    link_db = {}
    start_slash = re.compile('/')
    print link
    fullLink = link.attrs.get('href', None)
    check_start = start_slash.match(fullLink)
    if check_start != None:
        fullLink = base_site + fullLink
    page_child = urlopen(fullLink).read()
    soup_child = BeautifulSoup(page_child)
    link_db[fullLink] = 'example'
    return link_db

if __name__ == '__main__':
    base_site = "http://www.tasq.com"
    page = urlopen(base_site).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
    links = soup.find_all('a')
    link_dbs = []
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
    result = pool.map_async(work, links)
    link_dbs.extend( result.get() )
    print link_dbs
```

Take this as guideline though, I simplified your function to make it clearer. Hopefully this will get you on track.

Comment: Thanks, Yeray.  I don't have time to mess around with this until later today but I'll get back to you.  I appreciate the quick response.

Comment: Why do you include the `if __name__ == '__main__':` line?

Comment: From the [introduction in the multiprocessing doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing#introduction): 

**Note:
Functionality within this package requires that the __main__ module be importable by the children.** Without it the child processes would spawn children of their own.